# Styling the customized context menu in Forge viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I'm looking for a way to separate custom created context menu visually (like `background color` etc.)  from the default menu options like (`Show properties, Isolate, etc.`)

I've seen this example:

```
menu.push({
        title: 'Show details',
        className: 'fa fa-share',
        target: [{
          title: 'Hub details',
          className: 'fa fa-cloud',
          target: () => {
            this.emit('context.details', {
              event, node, type: 'hubs'
            })
          }
        }]
      })
```

but it seems `className` key doesn't work here. Is there a way to style context menu ?

Answer (score 1):

The class name for your custom icon must be set to a property called `icon`, not `className`. Running the following code snippet works as expected:

```js
NOP_VIEWER.registerContextMenuCallback('test', (menu, status) => {
    menu.push({
        title: 'Test',
        icon: 'adsk-icon-first-person',
        target: () => { console.log('It works!'); }
    });
});
```

[image]

Comment: thank you very much this approach is working like you showed. 

But does this mean that added context menus can be styled only on icon option but not CSS like background-color etc. ?

Comment: Well, the `icon` field is meant to be set to a CSS class that will add an icon to the menu item, but there's nothing preventing you from adding other CSS properties in the class rule as well.